# Is there a graph that cannot be colored by k colors for k greater than its chromatic number?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Is there a graph that is not proper color-able using exactly *k* colors where *k* greater than the chromatic number (and smaller than number of vertices)?

Comment: No.  Start with the minimum number of colors and swap in the additional colors (one per vertex) wherever a color was used more than once,

Comment: When you say "is not colorable" are there any restrictions? I can always color a graph with one color. Granted, unless I am looking at an empty graph that will not be a PROPER coloring. Is that what you meant or did you have some other restriction in mind?

Comment: @SE318 I mean coloring same as [*k*-coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) definition with one change: "exactly" instead of "at-most".

Comment: @hardmath looks like a solution, be sure to post it as an answer if there are no counter-examples(and thinking about it, I am convinced there are none).

Comment: @wondra a $k$-coloring is defined just to be a function $c:V(G)\to[k]$. It has no restrictions about adjacent vertices. If that is the case then you can choose any random $k$ vertices and coloring them $1$ through $k$ then color the rest $1$.

Comment: @SE318 to be absolutely precise(I hope) "proper *k*-coloring". Sorry, I did not payed attention to this because looking at the wiki page word "proper" seems widely implicit when talking about k-coloring.

Comment: @wondra now that I look at the Wikipedia article, I see where your confusion comes from. I would suggest that you always specify because proper colorings aren't studied as much anymore as other types of colorings(mostly because we have so many good results in proper colorings, without some kind of big breakthrough there isn't a lot of room for new interesting results). Colorings with other restrictions are still studied a lot though since there are still non-trivial but obtainable results for these colorings.

Comment: @MorganRodgers While it is a good assumption for the most part, I don't see any drawback to being unambiguous. A few examples where coloring would probably mean non-proper, "for a graph $G$ let $C_k(G)$ be the set of all $k$-colorings of $G$" I would read that to mean unrestricted colorings unless otherwise qualified. "Consider a random $k$-coloring of a graph $G$" again, I would take that to mean unrestricted coloring. Most of the time people will understand what you mean, but it's better if all the time they understand what you mean. It is good to get into a habit of being precise IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G = G(V,E)$ be a simple undirected graph.

The chromatic number $\chi(G)$ is the minimum number of colors needed for [a (vertex) coloring of $G$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring), so:

$$ \chi(G) \le |V| $$

since assigning a different color to each vertex avoids having adjacent vertices of the same color.

In the problem it is supposed that $k$ colors are available:

$$ \chi(G) \le k \le |V| $$

Start with a coloring that uses the minimum number $\chi(G)$ of colors.

Then any additional colors $k - \chi(G)$ can be used as replacements, one per vertex, wherever one of the original $\chi(G)$ colors is used more than once.  Such vertices must exist by a pigeonhole argument, so long as $k \le |V|$.

Since the additional colors are used only once, the distinct coloring of adjacent vertices is preserved by this procedure.  Thus $k$ colors can always be used, up to the limit of $|V|$.